# How can I cut the character from "Thu Jun 2 08:11:53 PDT 2016" such that to display only 08 11

Tags: text-processing

How can I cut the character from "Thu Jun 2 08:11:53 PDT 2016" such that to display only "08 11"

Comment: Is this a file or a content of a file.

Answer (score 4):

```
cut -d ' ' -f 4 | cut -d : -f 1,2 | tr : ' '
```

Or:

```
awk -F '[ :]' '{print $4, $5}'
```

Or:

```
sed 's/.* \(..\):\(..\):.*/\1 \2/'
```

If you've got it in a variable, with POSIX shells, you can do:

```
string='Thu Jun 2 08:11:53 PDT 2016'
IFS=': ' # split on colon and space
set -f   # disable glob
set -- $string # use the split+glob operator (unquoted variable)
h_m="$4 $5"
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's a simple output of the `date` command, you can run `date` with some parameters to output exactly what you want :

```
date '+%H %M'
```

If it's a file or a variable, you can `cat` or `echo` it then use `cut`, `awk` or `sed` as others mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If it a file then use this

```
# cat file
Thu Jun 2 08:11:53 PDT 2016
# cat file |  awk '{print $4}' | awk -F : '{print $1 " " $2}'
08 11
```

Comment: you don't need `cat`. Simply `awk '{print $4}' file | awk -F : '{print $1 " " $2}'`

Comment: @jcbermu You don't need the second process either: see [Stephane's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287115/6761)...

Comment: I just gave an example which came form the file. anyways thanks both for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the output of `date` or a similar program, so that the width of the string remains constant:

```
cut --output-delimiter=" " -c 11-12,14-15
```